# Angular 5 production deploy in IIS error

Tags: angular, iis, angular5, production

After I created web app with angular 5 I tried to deploy it in IIS.
In order to get the production build I used the command:

> ng build --prod

After I generated the dist folder I created a new IIS website, that uses the dist folder as src.
When I tried to browse the website I got only the background image with some unclear console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined

I would like to note that the web app works fine when I run it with npm start,
so why the production build isn't?

How can I solve this problem or at least get some clue about the error?

Comment: Production build makes use of aot while development build jit ,your error is giving you enough clue it says module type is undefined check your code where you have used this object or method without code it's quite hard to tell you the cause.

Comment: I've searched for 'moduleType' in the whole solution (with ctrl f) and it's not exist. @Vikas

Comment: send a screenshot of the error?

Comment: if you are using vscode  search with `ctrl+shift+f`

Comment: Try remove the "base" tag in your .html and close the < script> tags (NOT < script src="..."/>, YES < script scr="..."></ script>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `ng build --prod --aot=false` and then copy your dist to IIS and see if that works, if it works then you have an issue with your AOT build.

You may also wanna add: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your index.html
That caused me some errors before too.